# Incorrect result when trying to get rows to sort by date

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have custom code to get users ordering by `updated_at` column:

```
$customers = \App\Customer::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
   $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC');
})->get();
```

**Table scheme:**

```
 Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->string('lastname')->nullable();
    $table->string('surname')->nullable();
    $table->text('about')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

You can see [here](https://otabek.ga/test/query) query result. Why I get wrong result or my query is incorrect?

Comment: please provide your table schema.

Comment: @Bhoomipatel You can see my table scheme on updated question. My users table has laravel default users table scheme.

Comment: Are you trying to get ordered records according to customer table timestamp or user? @AndreasHunter

Comment: Your query is wrong. Inverse the relationship if you want to sort by users updated_at

Comment: So if you want user's information why not call from users and collect customer information from user and sorting on user model directly.  @AndreasHunter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to sort your customers and not the `user` relation you have to use `orderBy` on the `Customer` result:

```
$customers = \App\Customer::whereHas('user')
                            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
```

And as you do not want to order the users you don't need to use `whereHas()`. A simple `has()` should be fine:

```
$customers = \App\Customer::has('user')
                            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
                            ->get();
```

Comment: you ansewer not work correctly for me. You can see query results [here](https://otabek.ga/test/query) I've in customer model `belongsTo` relationships for `User` eloquent and I need sort by `users.updated_at` column and get customers. Users activity saved in my `users` table so i need this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
$customers = \App\Customer::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
             $query->orderBy('users.updated_at', 'DESC');
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I suspect you're trying to retrieve the relationship as well in order. You need to eager load, order by and use has:

```
$customers = \App\Customer::with(['user' => function ($query) {
   $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC');
})->whereHas('user')->get();
```

This should get the relationship and filter out all customers who don't have a user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, maybe it works for you:

```
$query = App\Customer::join('users as user', 'user.id', '=', 'customers.user_id')
                     ->orderBy('user.updated_at', 'desc')
                     ->select('customers.*')->get();
```